# RTC wake up circuit problems

Tags: microcontroller, transistors

I am building a project that uses a MCU to read data from various sensors every hour, and I'm aiming to use a RTC to wake it up.

The circuit uses two transistors that are controlled with the alarm flag of the RTC and a pin from the MCU respectively and when activated, both enable another transistor that powers up the MCU. It looks like this:
[image]

R3 is the load where the MCU would be.

This circuit works like this:

1. The RTC activates the switch that powers the MCU
2. The now powered MCU enables it's conroll pin to hold the switch open
3. The MCU tells the RTC to toggle the alarm flag

The circuit works as it stands, I put a resistor in Vout and the voltage is stable. The problems come when i plug the MCU to Vout, because when I do it the voltage starts to tremble and go up and down a bit which causes the microcontroller to reset every 2 or 3 seconds.

Have you had any issues like that? how could I solve it?

Comment: Are the signals on short links with twisted pairs? If not then EMI loops can be the cause. Also both input Off signals need to be 5V( vs) 3.3V ( not.) Input R is >100K in off-state and susceptible to stray E fields.  1nF cap is another fix.

Comment: It might sound obvious but do you have a decoupling cap on your MCU? Any short term changes in current draw may cause the fluctuations you are seeing.

Comment: Sorry I haven't time to do the maths on this or give a proper explanation. Can I recommend these changes. Remove R1. Move Q1 and Q4 base pull-up resistor supplies from their emitters and to the 5V supply, make them 100K. Give it a try.

Comment: I think you'll find that the 'leakage' current flowing into the MCU from Q4 through 'MCU In' is the cause of your trouble. I suggest you change Q4 to an NPN and invert the control signal from the MCU.

Answer (score 1):

The problem is probably a combination of:

- a low base current at Q2.
- a low current gain for Q2.
- not enough capacitance on the output.

Let's say that Q1 and Q4 are working as hard as they can to drive R2 low. We then have, across R2: 5V - 0.6V (Q1/Q4 Vbe) - 0.6V (Q2 Vbe) = 3.8V. So it makes a current of 0.8mA. If we consider that it all comes from Q2's base (we ignore R10), and considering a typical Hfe gain of about 150 for Q2 (see datasheet) it means that **you are not allowed to draw more than ~120mA before the output starts dropping dramatically** (and this is using the typical current gain, but using the datasheet min Hfe of 40, that would make only about **30mA**).

120mA on average is largely enough for most small MCUs. However, if you don't have enough bypass capacitance, the transient spikes at each clock cycle could reach this. And if you got unlucky and have a low current gain on Q2, the critical point is really close. Maybe you also have other loads in addition to the MCU itself (a few LEDs quickly adds up significant current).

The solution could be:

- lowering R2 (has the drawback of consuming more power)
- changing Q4 for a mosfet (nicer solution, but choose one with low gate threshold)
- eventually adding more capacitance on the output (the relevance of this suggestion depends on what you currently have).

Also check what is your total load at the output, of course.

Comment: Thanks for the detailed answer, but this is not the problem. I tried with different transistors and resistor values so it can draw more than 150mA (tested with a 3W LED) yet when I plug the MCU it still fails to mantain the voltage

Comment: What capacitance do you have? What is your load current?

Comment: I don't know how to calculate capacitance. The load current it should be about 500 mA but i'm testing it just with the MCU now, which should not be higher than 20 mA.

Comment: You don't have to *calculate* capacitance. You have to tell me the value of the capacitor you have put across the MCU supply (or, in other words, between the output of the above circuit and ground). And if, as I begin to suspect, if you *didn't* put any capacitor there, believe me, it *is* your problem.

Comment: Ok yeah, I tried using various capacitators i had in hand: 100 uF , 37 uF and 4.7uF, and none of them worked. Do you think i should use higher value capacitors? should I use smaller ones? I am still not very experienced in electronics.

Comment: A high value like that is a very good thing. But you should also have, in addition, a ceramic bypass capacitor of smaller value (100n to 1µ) put as close as possible to the MCU supply pins.

Answer (score 1):

In addition to ensuring that the processor has adequate bypass caps to allow reliable operation when switched on, it's will also be necessary to ensure that the device will reliably switch off and draw very little current when it's not supposed to be on.  If the RTC supply voltage is less than 4.3 volts (as it often would be), and its output has a clamp diode to its supply (as some might), there would be a continuous current through a few resistors and the clamp diode.

I'd suggest a circuit more like [this Falstad-simulator circuit](http://www.falstad.com/circuit/circuitjs.html?cct=$+1+0.000005+10.20027730826997+50+5+50%0At+336+128+336+80+1+-1+-0.58943586645072+-0.6644690459240215+100%0At+384+272+336+272+0+1+0.47129282023646824+0.5823679623491601+100%0Ar+304+80+304+128+0+10000%0Aw+304+128+336+128+0%0Aw+320+80+304+80+0%0Ar+336+128+336+256+0+3300%0Ar+384+272+464+272+0+56000%0Ar+384+272+384+304+0+10000%0Aw+336+288+336+304+0%0Aw+384+304+336+304+0%0Ag+336+304+336+336+0%0Aw+304+80+96+80+0%0Av+96+320+96+80+0+0+40+5+0+0+0.5%0Ag+96+320+96+336+0%0Ag+176+320+176+336+0%0Av+176+320+176+224+0+0+40+3+0+0+0.5%0Aw+240+208+304+208+0%0A172+240+304+240+352+0+6+5+5+0+0+0.5+Voltage%0At+176+224+240+224+0+1+-1.3355309540759785+-2.00000000011+100%0Ar+240+304+240+240+0+2200%0Aw+352+80+512+80+0%0Ar+528+112+528+224+0+100%0A172+464+272+496+272+0+6+5+5+0+0+0.5+Voltage%0A174+528+48+512+112+0+10000+0.9950000000000001+Resistance%0Ag+528+224+528+256+0%0Aw+304+208+304+128+0%0Ap+512+80+448+64+1+0%0A).  The first variable-voltage slider on the right side of the screen sets the voltage out of the RTC output (low=on); note that no current will flow until that voltage gets significantly below 3 volts.  The second variable-voltage slider sets the voltage out of the processor's keep-alive output which I have changed to active high.  As drawn, it needs to be almost 5 volts to keep the thing on.  If the controller will be running at a lower voltage, reduce the value of the 56K resistor.  Because controllers may misbehave in arbitrary fashion when VDD gets too low, the circuit should be designed so that the voltage required to turn the circuit on exceeds the minimum operating voltage of the controller.  Since the control can't output a voltage higher than VDD, such a design will ensure that even if a controller malfunctions when VDD drops to 2 volts and tries to turn itself back on, it won't be able to output a high enough voltage to do so.

An alternative circuit with MOSFETs would be [here](http://www.falstad.com/circuit/circuitjs.html?cct=$+1+0.000005+10.20027730826997+50+5+50%0Ar+272+80+272+192+0+10000%0Aw+272+192+336+192+0%0Aw+320+80+272+80+0%0Ar+384+272+464+272+0+4700%0Ar+384+272+384+304+0+10000%0Aw+336+288+336+304+0%0Aw+384+304+336+304+0%0Ag+336+304+336+336+0%0Aw+272+80+96+80+0%0Av+96+320+96+80+0+0+40+5+0+0+0.5%0Ag+96+320+96+336+0%0Ag+176+320+176+336+0%0Av+176+320+176+224+0+0+40+3+0+0+0.5%0Aw+240+192+272+192+0%0A172+240+304+240+352+0+6+5+5+0+0+0.5+Voltage%0Aw+352+80+512+80+0%0Ar+528+112+528+224+0+100%0A172+464+272+496+272+0+6+5+5+0+0+0.5+Voltage%0A174+528+48+512+112+0+10000+0.9851000000000001+Resistance%0Ag+528+224+528+256+0%0Aw+240+208+240+192+0%0Ap+512+80+448+64+1+0%0Af+176+224+240+224+16+1.5+0.02%0Af+384+272+336+272+16+1.5+0.02%0Af+336+128+336+80+17+1.5+0.02%0Aw+240+304+240+240+0%0Aw+336+256+336+192+0%0Aw+336+192+336+128+0%0A), though the simulation's MOSFETs can't handle much power, and the switching characteristics of MOSFETs are more varied than those of bipolar transistors.  Depending upon the switching characteristics of the actual right-hand MOSFET, the resistors may need to be adjusted to achieve a desired switching threshold, but the MOSFET circuit otherwise offers the advantage of reduced component count and lower quiescent current.

Comment: I tried the circuit but the problem is still there, I've noticed that the current i can draw is low. What should I change in order to make it draw more current, for instance 700 mA? thanks

Comment: @AlexP: The 2.2K resistor will affect the amount of current the circuit can draw when enabled by the RTC, and the 3.3K will affect the current it can draw when enabled by the CPU.  The 56K will set the voltage necessary from the CPU to turn the circuit on.  Reducing the first two resistors will increase the amount of current the circuit can supply, but will also increase the quiescent current it will consume while it is switched on.  More significantly, the circuit as drawn requires that the RTC sink all the base current for the primary transistor.  If the RTC can sink 4mA...

Comment: ...the circuit would be limited to supplying about 120mA-150mA.  If your current demands are higher than that, the circuit could be configured to add an extra gain stage coming off the RTC, but I'd suggest that you might be better off using a regulator with an on-off control input or else using MOSFETs if you know how those work.

Comment: @AlexP: I added a MOSFET circuit if you're interested.